# Explanation of the formula $df^{-1} = df\circ f^{-1}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Can someone explain the formula (for sufficiently nice $f$),

$$df^{-1} = df\circ f^{-1}$$

So far, I have tried working with the relation $df^{-1} = (df)^{-1}$ and the chain rule but I am not able to get anywhere.

---

Edit after the question has been answered:

The formula has turned out to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the inverse function theorem. I think you're missing a reciprocal (or inverse if you're in $\Bbb R^n$) on the right hand side. Note that $d(f\circ f^{-1}) = 1$. Can you see how this helps you?

Comment: So I am supposed to get $(df\circ f)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes you should. Take for example $f(x) = e^x$, then we know that $f^{-1}(x) = \ln x$. $df^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $df(x) = e^x$. However $(df\circ f^{-1})(x) = x$ when we should have gotten $\frac{1}{x}$ by your formula. The discrepancy is the inverse that I mentioned.

Comment: That would explain the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Of course :) glad it helped.

Comment: Even though the question is close now,  $d(f\circ f^{-1}) = dx$ and not $1$

Comment: @Arashium Good point. I was assuming $d$ was just shorthand for the total derivative, not the differential given the level of the question (real analysis instead of differential geometry).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you're working on the real line $\Bbb R$ with single-variable functions. Notice that: $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x, \quad \forall\, x \in {\rm dom}(f)$$
By the chain rule, we get: $$(f^{-1})'(f(x)) \, f'(x) = 1.$$
If $f'(x) \neq 0$, we go on: $$(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = (f'(x))^{-1},$$ and if $y = f(x)$, we finally get: $$(f^{-1})'(y) = (f'(f^{-1}(y)))^{-1}.$$

---

If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$, for all $p \in \Bbb R^n$, recall that ${\rm d}f_p: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ is a linear map. And we have: $$f^{-1} \circ f = {\rm Id} \implies {\rm d}(f^{-1} \circ f)_p = {\rm d}({\rm Id})_p.$$
We use that ${\rm d}({\rm Id})_p = {\rm Id}$, since the identity is linear, and we use the chain rule to get: $${\rm d}(f^{-1})_{f(p)}\circ {\rm d}f_p = {\rm Id} \implies {\rm d}(f^{-1})_{f(p)} = ({\rm d}f_p)^{-1}.$$